# How to evaluate a dollar expression in groovy and store the value

Tags: amazon-web-services, groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell

I have a need where i need to retrieve the Revision for a task def in AWS using my Jenkinsfile groovy. The below works for me under a shell script, but i have been unable to get it working for my Jenkinsfile groovy. The other variables like props.region ,etc are coming from a properties file and i am already getting those using :-

```html
def call(Map config=[:]) {
    def deployDefinition = libraryResource "deployDefinitions/ecs/${config.deployApplication}/${config.deployEnvironment}.properties"
    def props = readProperties(text:deployDefinition)
    
    withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', credentialsId: "${props.awsCreds}", secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {
    
    def newimageurl = "${props.registry}/${props.imagename}:${IMAGE_TAG}"
    def oldimageurl = "${props.registry}/${props.imagename}"
    
    sh "sed -i -e 's#${oldimageurl}#${newimageurl}#' ./taskdef.json"
      
   sh "aws ecs register-task-definition --family ${props.family} --cli-input-json file://${WORKSPACE}/taskdef.json --region ${props.region}"
   REVISION=$(aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition ${props.task_def_name} --region ${props.region} | jq .taskDefinition.revision)
   sh "aws ecs update-service --cluster ${props.cluster} --region ${props.region} --service ${props.service_name} --task-definition ${props.task_def_name}:$REVISION"
}
}
```

```html
REVISION=$(aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition ${props.task_def_name} --region ${props.region} | jq .taskDefinition.revision)
```

All i am looking for is how to retrieve the actual value for REVISION so that i can pass that value in my next command which is to update the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working using the below approach :-

```html
sh "aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition ${props.task_def_name} --region ${props.region} | jq .taskDefinition.revision > output.txt"
def REVISION = readFile "${WORKSPACE}/output.txt"
sh "aws ecs update-service --cluster ${props.cluster} --region ${props.region} --service ${props.service_name} --task-definition ${props.task_def_name}:$REVISION"
```